# cannot install R.basic package-source connection

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to install r.basic, and I use to connect the source

```
>source("http://www.braju.com/R/hbLite.R")
```

​
but it returns me error message:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (null)'
```

Whats the mean and how should I do?
Thank you​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URL you provide is redirected to a different URL: http://www.aroma-project.org/hbLite.R

Your browser likely automatically transfers you to the new URL so you may not notice. Try using the new URL.